# Android Pay: Public, Private Key Pair generation (Elliptic Curve with NISTP-256)

Tags: java, android, android-pay

Android Pay Issue

In Android Pay the process to generate a token from a credit card is as follows:

Generate a public and private key (the calls below return the keys using an Elliptic Curve with  NISTP-256 algorithm)

To do this I call ...

```
public static KeyPair generateKeyPair() {
  KeyPair pair =null;
  try {
    ECGenParameterSpec ecGenSpec = new ECGenParameterSpec("prime256v1");
    java.security.KeyPairGenerator g = KeyPairGenerator.getInstance("EC");
    g.initialize(ecGenSpec, new SecureRandom());
    pair = g.generateKeyPair();
    pair.getPrivate();
    pair.getPublic();
  }catch (Throwable e ){
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
  return pair;
}
```

… This successfully returns the public and private key, but I am not sure what the format/encoding of the keys is in. I could not find any documentation on this.

Question 1: Is this the right way to generate a public and private key for Android Pay?

Pass the public key in base64 encoded format to the Android Pay `createMaskedWalletRequet` method (details of this are in the Android Pay documentation)

```
String publicKey = String (Base64.encodeBase64(pair.getPublic().getEncoded()));

PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters parameters = PaymentMethodTokenizationParameters.newBuilder().setPaymentMethodTokenizationType(PaymentMethodTokenizationType.NETWORK_TOKEN).addParameter("publicKey", publicKey).build();
```

Here I get the following exception:

> 03-30 17:02:06.459 3786-15263/? E/WalletClient: Error validating
>   MaskedWalletRequest.paymentMethodTokenizationParameters: first byte of
>   parameter "publicKey" must be 0x04 (which indicates uncompressed point
>   format)

Question 2: Can you please help me understand what I am doing wrong. I think this may be related to a format mismatch, but not sure, and not sure how to fix it.

Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 5):

Answer 1:

According to Android Pay document you can generate public key by OpenSSL like this:
https://developers.google.com/android-pay/integration/gateway-processor-integration#example-using-openssl-to-generate-and-format-a-public-key[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/android-pay/integration/gateway-processor-integration#example-using-openssl-to-generate-and-format-a-public-key)

Then generate private key use

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in merchant-key.pem -nocrypt
```

Or you can use a shell script file.(example: genkey.sh in [Android pay quickstart](https://github.com/android-pay/androidpay-quickstart))
Use the following code(copy code to .sh file and double click) you can get private key.

```
#!/bin/bash

# Generate key.pem file:
openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out key.pem

# Print public and private key in hex form:
openssl ec -in key.pem -text -noout

openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in key.pem -nocrypt

sleep 2m
```

Then copy pub string in terminal and replace in this code then save this code to create .sh file again

```
#!/bin/bash

KEY="04:a9:9b:54:81:b0:67:0d:d3:50:84:e0:d4:d2:29:
    a5:3a:d6:5c:21:ae:5e:dd:58:75:f0:27:63:44:e8:
    a9:86:8d:cf:17:64:63:96:54:34:ed:16:37:c4:37:
    e6:b7:27:ad:06:af:b0:07:d1:b5:66:0a:2a:85:c0:
    71:9e:cc:39:54"

echo $KEY | xxd -r -p | base64
sleep 2m
```

Then get public key.

Answer 2:
You can test by these keys:

Public Key:
BKmbVIGwZw3TUITg1NIppTrWXCGuXt1YdfAnY0ToqYaNzxdkY5ZUNO0WN8Q35rcnrQavsAfRtWYKKoXAcZ7MOVQ=

(This public key can pass as a string to MaskedWalletRequet directly)

Private Key:
MIGHAgEAMBMGByqGSM49AgEGCCqGSM49AwEHBG0wawIBAQQgTA/wqrlbeVddorTlaT1AqhALrIBwS+DUdV3N1K1gImqhRANCAASpm1SBsGcN01CE4NTSKaU61lwhrl7dWHXwJ2NE6KmGjc8XZGOWVDTtFjfEN+a3J60Gr7AH0bVmCiqFwHGezDlU

Comment: Thanks Andy, we did exactly same and generated static Public and Private key pair and used it in our application. I was thinking if there was way to dynamically generate them, but google was ok with using static key pair

Answer (score 0):

The problem is in generating the keys. I had faced a similar issue. To resolve this I'm calling shell commands from java code to generate keys. PFB.

```
String pemPath = "/path for storing pem path";

//To generate pem file
executeSH("openssl ecparam -name prime256v1 -genkey -noout -out "+pemPath+"key.pem",true);

//To obtain publicKeyString from pem file
String publicKeyString = executeSH(new String[]{"/bin/sh", "-c", "openssl ec -in key.pem -pubout -text -noout | grep -A5 pub: | tail -5 | xxd -r -p | base64"},false);

//To obtain privateKeyString from pem file
String privateKeyString = executeSH("openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -inform PEM -outform PEM -in key.pem -nocrypt",false);
privateKeyString=privateKeyString.substring(27, 211);

//Deleteing PEM file
executeSH("rm "+ pemPath+"key.pem",false);

//executeSH function overload this function with commands[] parameter
private String executeSH(String command, boolean waitFor) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        Process process = null;
        InputStream inputStream = null;
        InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = null;
        BufferedReader bufferedReader = null;
        String line,output="";
        try {
            Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
            process = runtime.exec(command);
            inputStream = process.getInputStream();
            inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
            bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);

            while((line=bufferedReader.readLine())!=null){
                output += line;
            }
            if(waitFor){
                process.waitFor();
            }
            return output;
        } finally {
            if(bufferedReader!=null) bufferedReader.close();
            if(inputStreamReader!=null) inputStreamReader.close();
            if(inputStream!=null) inputStream.close();
            if(process!=null) process.destroy();
        }
    }
```